# What happened to Victor's car?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In Breaking Bad S04E01, Box Cutter- What happened to Victor's car? He left it at the crime scene, when he jumped in Jesse's car. Doubtful that anyone drove him, as he dashed over there at top speed. Nobody has mentioned this anywhere! This, in additional to being seen (just another lookyloo) would further explain Gus killing him.

Answer (score 1):

Since the ABQ police never used the vehicle to trace their investigation back to Victor (it's a common investigative technique for police officers to document license plates and then check them against wanted person, theft reports or known felons.) and since the series scrupulously avoids demonstrating US law enforcement taking bribes, it safe to presume that following the removal of Gail's body, Mike Ehrmentraut sent one of his men to retrieve the vehicle.

The narrative veers away from Victor following his murder in the underground drug lab, so any details of his life prior to his demise and any repercussions that his death might have had (other than depriving Mike fo a trusted confidante) are left dangling. Even Victor's presence at the crime scene (where he is witnessed by several people staring into Gail's apartment and then fleeing rapidly) is never addressed which is odd as it would have made him at least a "person of interest" in the eyes of the police.

The series demonstrates (until the aftermath of Gus Fring's death) that the Fring crime syndicate runs with almost inhuman levels of efficiency. The fact that they ran a multimillion dollar drug that was undetected by the ABQ police and the DEA indicate that. So it doesn't appear to be a stretch to presume that this same group could have easily removed a suspect vehicle from a crime scene and then dispose of that vehicle in a manner that prevented its discovery by law enforcement.